# Vectors in linked lists

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

struct Monomial
{
    int coefficient;
    int degree;
    Monomial *next;
};

class Polynomial
{
private:
    Monomial *first;
    Monomial *last;
public:
    Polynomial(){
        first = NULL;
        last = NULL;
    }
    ~Polynomial(){}

    void generate_polynomial(vector<vector<int>> V) {
        Monomial *new_node = new Monomial();
        new_node -> coefficient = V; 
        new_node -> degree = V;
        new_node -> next =  NULL;

        if(first == NULL){
            first = last = new_node;
        }
        else{        
            last->next = new_node;
            last = new_node;
        }


    }

    void print_polynomial(){

    }

    void derivative(){

    }

    void slope_at_point(int k){

    }

    void tangent_line_at_point(int k){

    }

};

int main()
{
    Polynomial P;
   // Polynomial D;
   // Polynomial T;

    vector<vector<int>> V = {{2, 6}, {-4, 5}, {1, 4}, {-9, 3}, {8, 2}, {5, 1}, {-6, 0}};

    P.generate_polynomial(V);
    //P.print_polynomial();
    //D = P.derivative();
    //D.print_polynomial();
    //cout << P.slope_at_point(7) << endl;
    //T = P.tangent_line_at_point(7);
    //T.print_polynomial();
    return 0;
}
```

I am having a problem with both lines 31 and 32, I know if we were to not be passing a vector and instead had

```
void generate_polynomial(int value){
```

lines 31 and 32 would read

```
new_node -> coefficient = value ;
new_node -> degree = value;
```

but since Im passing a 2D vector in as a parameter, im getting confused on what I should put it equal to. As of right now I get the error "expected primary expression before 'int'" for both lines 31 and 32.

Comment: Tactical note: if `V` always contains an array of paired values, consider `std::array<int, 2>` or `std::pair<int, int>`. Significant performance improvements to be had by storing all of the stat in one contiguous block.

Comment: you are passing what is effecirvely a 2d array into that function. What do you want that function to do? in words not code Do you want to make a Monmial for each entry or just one, if just one, which one ?

Comment: @pm100 I would like it to make a monomial for each entry

Comment: The degree of a monomial is the sum of the exponents of the variables. I don't think `new_node -> degree = value;` will cut it. Mind you, you could be misusing the term monomial.

Comment: Don't use `vector<int>` for the pair of coefficient and degree. A `pair<int, int>` would make it clear it's always 2 values. A struct with named members would be even more readable.

Answer (score 1):

OK based on you answer - "I would like to make a Monmial for each entry"

```
void generate_polynomial(vector<vector<int>> V) {
    for (auto& outer : V) {
     
            Monomial* new_node = new Monomial();
            new_node->coefficient = inner;
            new_node->degree = inner;
            new_node->next = NULL;
            if (first == NULL) {
                first = last = new_node;
            }
            else {
               last->next = new_node;
               last = new_node;
             }
         }
     }
  }
```

I suspect this is wrong, in that you probably want coefficient to be inner[0] and degree to be inner[1]. But I can only go on what you said.

EDIT

```
void generate_polynomial(vector<vector<int>> V) {


    for (auto& entry : V) {

        Monomial* new_node = new Monomial();
        new_node->coefficient = entry[0];
        new_node->degree = entry[1];
        new_node->next = NULL;
        if (first == NULL) {
            first = last = new_node;
        }
        else {
            last->next = new_node;
            last = new_node;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have misunderstood your question. You're completely right, I would like to set the coefficient to inner[0] and degree to inner[1]

Comment: @user18444388 see edit

Comment: Thank you, I greatly appreciate it

Comment: @user18444388 the extensive redo of your code in rturrado answer is a more thorough solution since it resolves other issues with your code (memory leaks), it also more clearly expresses the intent of the vector V => ie an unbounded list of pairs of integers

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

- Passing a vector of monomials as `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>`.

```cpp
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> V{
        {2, 6},
        {-4, 5},
        {1, 4},
        {-9, 3},
        {8, 2},
        {5, 1},
        {-6, 0}
    };
```

- Using smart pointers for the list of monomials within `Polynomial`.

```cpp
struct Monomial {
    int coefficient{};
    int degree{};
    std::unique_ptr<Monomial> next{};
};

class Polynomial {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Monomial> first{};
    Monomial* last{};
};
```

- `generate_polynomial` just walks the list of monomials, creating a node from each coefficient and degree.

```cpp
    void generate_polynomial(const std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>& V) {
        for (const auto& [coefficient, degree] : V) {
            auto new_node{std::make_unique<Monomial>(coefficient, degree)};

            if (first == nullptr) {
                first = std::move(new_node);
                last = first.get();
            }
            else {
                last->next = std::move(new_node);
                last = last->next.get();
            }
        }
    }
```

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/4xPns7fP9)